# find row number boolean matrix maximum number 1s

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

*I have Boolean array *

```
var array=[[0 ,1 ,1 ,1],[0 ,0, 1, 1],[1 ,1 ,1 ,1],[0 ,0 ,0 ,0]]
```

how to find maximum-number of 1s 
I want to javascript solution 
Here is my aproch

```js
var array = [
  [0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

var indexValue = 0
var count = 0
array.forEach(function(element, index) {

  var value = element.reduce(function(a, b) {

    return a + b

  })
  if (value > count) {
    indexValue = index
  }

})
console.log(indexValue)
```

**This code is perfect but I want more optimization in my code**

Comment: i see no boolean ...

Comment: What is the issue with the code that it needs to be optimized?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum number of 1 ? Do you mean in a row ?

Comment: @user1474111 yes

Comment: there's a bug in your code (change the last row to `[0, 0, 0, 1]` to see it). Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: For ideas for optimisation of working code you should really post on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), provided your question is really not about a coding problem.

Comment: You never update `count`...

Comment: In the example there is never a 0 following a 1. Is this a rule?

Comment: I dont know about optimization per-say but if you wanted to rather than doing a reduction you could do something like ``element.filter(val => val == 1).length``. Might be a tiny bit nicer of a result however i dont thing its any more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt any more optimized from what i can tell, however it is an alternate way to solve your problem if you prefer it.

```js
var array = [
  [0, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

var indexValue = 0
var best = 0
array.forEach(function(element, index) {
   var val = element.filter(v => v == 1).length;
   if(val > best){
      best = val;
      indexValue = index;
   }
});
console.log(indexValue)
```